# How could I optimize this query ? 02

Tags: mysql

I'd like to know if you have some tips to improve this query:

```
select id, name, friends_count, post_count, from user where id in
(select distinct(id) from friends where id in
(24,245,888,765,907,203,3,972)) order by friends_count desc limit
0,10;
```

The explain output is:

```
+----+--------------------+----------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+--------+-------------------------------------------+ 
| id | select_type        | table    | type  | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref  | rows   | Extra                                     |
+----+--------------------+----------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+--------+-------------------------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY            | user     | ALL   | NULL          | NULL    | NULL    | NULL | 451302 | Using where; Using filesort               |  
|  2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | friends  | range | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 8       | NULL | 395816 | Using where; Using index; Using temporary |
+----+--------------------+----------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+--------+-------------------------------------------+
```

The index for user table is a Primary Key in id row. For friend there is a primary key form id and friend_id.

user table has about  587445 results and friend has 572515 (both growing).

The current query spent more than 20 min.

The dependent subquery give about 220.000 results, so the primary query has more than 220k ids in the where clausule.

Do you have some tips (index or something like) to improve this ?

Thanks and best regards.

Comment: select id, name, friends_count, post_count, from user where id in (24,245,888,765,907,203,3,972) order by friends_count desc limit 0,10; ?

Comment: no, i don't want users with that ids, I want friend users of these ids.

Comment: but this subquery seems wrong "select distinct(id) from friends where id in (24,245,888,765,907,203,3,972)"?

Comment: Hi  Hieu, you are right it was wront, it was distinct(friend_id). Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
select 
   id,
   name,
   friends_count,
   post_count,
from 
   user u
where 
   u.id in (4,245,888,765,907,203,3,972)
order by 
   friends_count desc 
limit 0,10;
```

You should never do nested selects in your where clause. You should always leverage joins where possible. If you don't, each comparison will require a select to the database which is a huge performance hit.

I corrected my query. Seems like friend_id and user_id are the same. If you let me know what the columns should be, I can update it.

Comment: Thanks Ryan now it flies!! I'll take your advice.

Comment: Beautiful and simple, I like it

Comment: Ryan, i have corrected, the friend table has 2 columns Ids friend_id and user_id. Now it works perfectly.